How to turn my internet to a proxy?
I would like to route my VPN traffic from a Windows virtual machine, utilizing a functioning HTTP/SOCKS5 proxy. My goal is to configure this setup to generate a usable IP, port, username, and password, which can then be used with the FoxyProxy browser extension.
Would it be possible to implement this configuration so that I can share the IP, port, username, and password with any people, allowing them to access the proxy as well?

The first determination, and information that must be shared, is if you are behind a CGNAT. Can you make that determination and then [edit] your question?
